# Problem with right $ and {} placed in math formula

Tags: math-mode, multline

I read a lot about math text formating in LaTeX but now I'm just confused about what is wrong in this formula.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{multline}
P(B_{1}) = P({A_{1}} \cap \text{\={A}_{2}} \cap \text{\={A}_{3}})\\
= P(A_{1})  * P(\text{\={A}_{2}}) * P(\text{\={A}_{3}})\\
 = 0,0001 * 0,9988 * 0,9998 = 0,0000997
\end{multline}
\end{document}
```

Can anybody help me with this?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: You can not use underline `_` inside `\text{}`. Why are you using `\text{}`?

Comment: sorry, my fault..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are using a weird way of putting bars on the A's (at least: I have never seen it done like that). You can use the `\bar` command for that. Try this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{multline}
P(B_{1}) = P({A_{1}} \cap \bar{A}_{2} \cap \bar{A}_{3})\\
= P(A_{1})  * P(\bar{A}_{2}) * P(\bar{A}_{3})\\
 = 0,0001 * 0,9988 * 0,9998 = 0,0000997
\end{multline}
\end{document}
```

Also, some suggestions: you can avoid the extra space after the decimal comma by wrapping the comma in curly braces. The asterisks for multiplication may look strange, so I suggest using `\times` instead. And you can align the equality signs with the `align` environment:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
P(B_{1}) 
& = P({A_{1}} \cap \bar{A}_{2} \cap \bar{A}_{3})\\
& = P(A_{1}) \times P(\bar{A}_{2}) \times P(\bar{A}_{3})\\
& = 0{,}0001 \times 0{,}9988 \times 0{,}9998 = 0{,}0000997
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what you want but here is a try:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\sisetup{
  output-decimal-marker = {,},
  group-digits = false
}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
  P(B_{1})
  &= P(A_{1} \cap \overline{A_{2}} \cap \overline{A_{3}})\\
  &= P(A_{1}) \cdot P(\overline{A_{2}}) \cdot P(\overline{A_{3}})\\
  &= \num{0.0001} \cdot \num{0.9988} \cdot \num{0.9998}\\
  &= \num{0.0000997}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Comment: Since the OP appears to prefer using `,` as the decimal marker (and didn't mention anything about grouping digits), you may want to add the instruction `\sisetup{output-decimal-marker={,}, group-digits=false}` to the preamble.